BLE connection using QTAsyncio and BLEAK
I'm trying to create a GUI to establish a connection over BLE with an ESP. For the GUI I'm using PySide6 and for the BLE connection the Bleak library. I used the following example as a reference to use PySide6 with asyncio (async needed for the bleak library):
https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/examples/example_async_minimal.html
I created a button to connect to the device in the following way:
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
    #Button to enable Connection
    self.connect_button = QPushButton("Connect")
    ...
    ...
    ...
    self.connect_button.clicked.connect(lambda: asyncio.ensure_future(self.connect_BLE()))

    async def connect_BLE(self):
        print("Connecting")
        async with bleak.BleakClient(address_or_ble_device="0C:DC:7E:CB:16:BE") as  client:
            await client.connect()
        print(client.is_connected)

The main method looks like this:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()

    QtAsyncio.run()

When I click the button I receive the following error:

QtTask.cancelling is not implemented

